# Action Function re-render not working

Tags: apex, custom-object

I have a selectlist on VF page as shown below. It is populated by a "getCustomerList()" method in the controller that queries the database:

```
<apex:selectList id="custList" onChange="recalculateProducts()" size="1" value="{!cs.Customer_Name__c}">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!CustomerList}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

and a second componenet that I would like to re-render when the first one is changed or a new value is selected. It is populated by a getProductTypes() method in the controller:

```
<apex:selectList id="productList" size="1" value="{!cs.Product_Type__c}">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!ProductTypes}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

I have an action function that calls the getProductTypes() method again onChange of the customer SelectList:

```
<apex:actionFunction id="refreshProducts" action="{!recalculateProducts}"  name="refreshProducts" rerender="trxList"/>
```

Below is the script for that action function:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function recalculateProducts (){

        refreshProducts();

                    }

</script>
```

Here are the two methods from the controller, the second one is the one I would like to run onChange:

```
public Set<SelectOption> getProductTypes(){

    Set<SelectOption> ProductTypes = new Set<SelectOption>();
        ProducttTypes.add(New SelectOption('Not Product Related', 'Not Product Related')); 

    String chosenCustomer = '';

    if (cs.Customer_Name__c != 'Not Product Related'){
        chosenType = 'option1';
    }
    else{
        chosenType = 'option2';
    }
    ProductTypes.add(new SelectOption(chosenType, chosenType));

    return ProductTypes;
}   

public PageReference refreshProducts (){
    getProductTypes();
    PageReference ProductRefresh = ApexPages.currentPage();
        return ProductRefresh;


}
```

The problem here is that the function does not seem to read cs.Customer_Name__c, and my action function does not run. No matter what I select, even if it is "Not Product Related," the page does not refresh and "option1" is always the option to select. How can I get my action function to call the recalcualteProducts javascript function and get that to call the method in the controller?

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: update  onChange="recalculateProducts()"  to  onChange="refreshProducts()"  in <apex:selectList id="custList">. Now create recalculateProducts() on your controller. It ll work.

Comment: And the <script>code</script> is not reqired. Action function is the javascript method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the function call slightly mixed up.
Your actionfunction works like this:

```
<apex:actionFunction id="refreshProducts" action="{!recalculateProducts}"  name="refreshProducts" rerender="trxList"/>
```

The **action** refers to the Apex controller method that you are trying to call.
The **name** is the javascript name that you call to invoke this.

So to trigger the actionfunction, you simply call `refreshProducts()`

ie, change this line `onChange="recalculateProducts()"` to this `onchange="refreshProducts()"`

Other things to try:
Change this:

```
PageReference ProductRefresh = ApexPages.currentPage();
return ProductRefresh;
```

To this:

```
return null;
```

Finally, try using a explicit variable to hold your products rather than a getter method. ie:

```
public productOptions Set<SelectOption> {get;set;}
//in the constructor, assign product options a value derived from your getter method, which you can rename from getProductTypes to calcProductTypes
//in the refreshProduct method, refresh the list like this:
productOptions = calcProductTypes();
```

Comment: it looks like this is correct in getting the action method to run, but it still appears that I cannot get it to re-render, as it is not reading the cs.Customer_Name__c field and it does not update. A couple more tries and I will mark this answer as correct, as it does fix getting the action function to run.

Comment: try changing onChange to onchange - I believe this attribute is case sensitive

Comment: no such luck there. It does not seem to read the onchanged" value.

Comment: I've added some of the other things you should try. Not using an automatic getter is a good idea, as you get to control when you assign values to the select list - using an automatic getter removes that control. Calling the automatic getter method in the PageReference method doesn't help - just think - what are you assigning the result to?